# Why is it needed to patch (or apply) diff after doing git pull

Tags: bash, git, github

I have a master branch that I'll never make local changes to, and I have a remote origin/master from where I get all of my changes. My company's script for doing this looks like the following:

git pull

git diff master..origin/master > p1
patch < p1 or use git apply to apply the diff instead of patch.

git add

git commit

My question is: Why is it needed to manually patch (or apply) a diff in order to get the new changes from origin/master? Doesn't the initial "git pull" already make sure master gets all the new changes from origin/master, and that the diffs are merged?

Comment: It's not (needed) in general. If there's any difference between the commits identified by `master` and `origin/master`, the patch will produce instructions for changing `master` to match `origin/master`, so applying the patch will change them to match. But if you start in such a state, and never make any changes, the diff should never have any differences, unless the upstream *removed* commits from history. If that won't happen, the process given here is pointless. If that *will* happen, there's a better process anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an exceptionally bad way of pulling from origin, as it will create separate commits, so master and origin/master will have divergent commits *even when the code is identical*. This is not how git is supposed to be used at all.

```
git pull
```

is all you need. This script is trying to reinvent the wheel, and was probably written by someone who didn't understand git very well.